# Info box similar to Google Image Search Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here are some factors I would like to borrow from Googles Image Search Results:

- Each item sits next to each other and falls to the next row if it cant fit in the current row because of the browser windows width.
- When one item is clicked on, an info box slides open directly below the row of the selected item, it fills the width of the browser, also an indicator is visible at the bottom of the selected item.
- When the info box is opened, if the browser width is changed, the items fall into a row that it can fill (top first) or fall into the row below. this does not affect the 100% width of the info box or its position directly below the row of the currently selected item.

I already have implemented the first bullet by creating DIVs that have `display: inline-block`

I want a solution thats mostly HTML and CSS first, and JavaScript (JQuery, AJAX etc.) only if necessary, I dont like using too many HTML attributes except for ones I'd need to make this work, like `id`, `class`, `src` etc. I usually use CSS whenever possible instead.

If I can stick to just HTML elements and then style them with CSS and what ever remnants can't be fulfilled with just CSS and HTML be fulfilled with JavaScript (or any derivative JQuery, AJAX etc).

an example of where im at so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div
                {
                     display: inline-block;
                     height: 200px;
                     width: 200px;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div>
           <img/>
       </div>
       <div>
           <img/>
       </div>
       <div>
           <img/>
       </div>
       <div>
           <img/>
       </div>
       <div>
           <img/>
       </div>
       <div>
           <img/>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: OK heres what I came up with, it does exactly what I wanted it to do, hope this helps anyone looking to do the same.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            "Some JavaScript/JQuery etc code that will,
             first put the 'info' DIV block right after
             the selected item (code-wise), then alternates
             the 'display' CSS property of the '.info' class
             from none to normal so it renders just below the
             selected item. Just changing none to normal is
             enough because of the 'clear' and 'float' properties."
        </script>
        <style>
            div.item
                {
                    background-color: blue;
                    border: red 5px solid;
                    display: inline-block;
                    height: 200px;
                    width: 200px;
                }

            div.info
                {
                    background-color: grey;
                    float: left;
                    clear: both;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 200px;
                    display: normal;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
       </div>
       <div class="info">
           Here lies some cool details about the item selected.
           Have your JS code put this DIV block right after the selected DIV block in code.
           You will notice that no matter how much you change the width of the browser,
           this block always remains under the selected item as long as your JavaScript
           put this code block directly after the selected item. 
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

try this and resize the browsers width while the `display` property of the `info` DIV is set to normal. You will notice all the item boxes rise above the `info` DIV as the width increases and they fall under it as the width decreases. Hope this helps someone ;D

Comment: Have you started working on the second and the third bullet? However, I can't wait to see the AJAX solution.

Comment: yes I have and I can accomplish the second bullet but not when the browsers width is changed, and I can't pre determine where the info box should expand because I have no way of knowing how many items are in each row when the page renders. Also this is odd, I've used this site before and have had great feedback on issues, idk what it is about this question but all I'm getting are downvotes, what did I do wrong here, I've searched about the internet and couldn't find anything, I thought this would have been the best place for it, guess not...?

Comment: @PetrR. after giving it some more thought and playing around with more CSS properties, I've figured it out, its a combination of the `clear` and `float` CSS properties, ill update my original question with the appropriate answer.

Comment: @PetrR.updated... see original question!

Comment: You're probably getting down votes because you're asking too much for a single question. You probably want to figure things out a step at a time and ask separate questions for specific problems, but only after you've tried coding something yourself. The StackOverflow community tends to like smaller, bite-sized questions based on helping you complete something you're already trying. (BTW, I didn't vote up or down.)

Comment: @Tech Thanks for updating the question. I canceled my downvote. Usually it's better to post a non-functional code than no code at all. Also, it's a good idea to include a [jsFiddle *or similar site* link](http://jsfiddle.net/) in your question in the future.

Comment: The thing is I have a version I did before I asked the question, but I thought it would be too long to post. So I super-gutted it out to the bare minimum and left only the factors I know would be needed to make this work, iI didn't want to bombard anyone with having to sift to many lines of code, I thought I was making my question easier to answer. @ChrisPeters

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid javascript as much as possible, you can create a `<div class='info'>` with the details about the image after each `<div class="item">` like so:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
</div>
<div class="info">
    Details about the first image.
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
</div>
<div class="info">
    Details about the second image.
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
</div>
<div class="info">
    Details about the third image.
</div>
```

---

After that, replace this line in your css:

```
div.info
{
    display: normal;
}
```

with:

```
div.info
{
    display: none;
}
```

This will make the details hidden when the page is loaded.

---

And finally, insert the following [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) code to make the details appear when `<div class="item">` is clicked:

```
$("div.item").click(function (){
    $("div.info").css("display", "none");
    $(this).find("+ div.info").css("display", "block"); 
});
```

---

### [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XnfJx/)

Comment: I like that idea, it results in less JavaScript and gets the job done, thank you for your solution.