# Javascript - Show div when a grid element is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

I have a 5*7 grid made of divs. I need to do something like in the Netflix interface: when the user clicks on one of these divs, a bigger div gets displayed underneath, with the width set as 100% of the parent container, pushing the next rows down in the page. When the user chooses to close it or clicks on another div in the page, it needs to go back to the initial configuration.

This is the initial situation:
[image: Initial grid]

And this is what I need to accomplish:
[image: When an element gets clicked]

**HTML** (Laravel framework):

```
<section class="content">
<div class="grid">
    @for ($i = 1; $i <= 35; $i++)
        <div class="gridcell" id="{{ $i }}">
            <h5>Spazio n° {{ $i }}</h5>
            @foreach ($auctions as $auction)
                @if ($auction->position == $i)
                    <img src="{{ $auction->imgUrl }}" alt=" {{ $auction->description }}">
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endfor 
</div>
</section>
```

**CSS**:

```
.grid {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.gridcell {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    min-height: 150px;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    min-height: 180px; 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Comment: look at js toggle function or if you have tried anything post your code

Comment: What you need is too complex for me to add here... you should checkout this article on how it's achieved. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

Comment: I think you can get the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17589996/2884831

Comment: @Aaron that's exactly what I was looking for! You saved me hours of research, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17589996/2884831

His jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XnfJx/

And his answer is listed below

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
</div>
<div class="info">
    Details about the first image.
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
</div>
<div class="info">
    Details about the second image.
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="some_relative_image.png"/>
</div>
<div class="info">
    Details about the third image.
</div>
```

css:

```
div.info
{
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$("div.item").click(function (){
    $("div.info").css("display", "none");
    $(this).find("+ div.info").css("display", "block"); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/cwe03u4j/4/

I tried to make something along those lines

html

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="col1">1</div>
    <div class="col1">2</div>
    <div class="col1">3</div>
    <div class="col1">4</div>

    <div class="drop"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.col1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px black solid;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#container {
    width: 420px;
}

.drop {
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: none;
}
```

js

```
$(".col1").on("click", function() {
    var info = $(this).html();
    if ($(".drop").html() == $(this).html() || !$(".drop").hasClass('active'))
        $(".drop").slideToggle().toggleClass('active').html(info);      
    else
        $(".drop").html(info);
});
```

Comment: When I click on another one then it would be nice if it would show the other one but right now it closes the block.

Comment: 1st click doesn't trigger anything, requires a second click to show the box below.